# Gradle retrofit failed to resolve

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

This is my first time trying to use gradle with an android project. I would like to add retrofit to my project but it keeps telling me.

> Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0
>
> Failed to resolve: com.squareup.okhttp:2.2.0

However google play services works perfectly.

My gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "test.gradel"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
  compile group: "com.squareup.retrofit", name: "retrofit", version: "1.9.0"
  compile group: "com.squareup.okhttp", name: "okhttp", version: "2.2.0"
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
  } 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Works fine. Check your internet connection. Also attach your top-level build.gradle file.

Comment: I think that is my problem. I do not have a top-level build.gradle file in the project

Comment: @Ziem thank you that was the issue.

Comment: @CodePorter Post your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed by creating a higher level build.gradle file and moved the following code into it.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify where you can find these artifacts.
You have to add a *repository block* in your script.

You have to add this to your build.gradle

```
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }
```

or

```
 repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
```

The Google play services library works because it is located in the Google Repository, which is downloaded with SDK Manager.

Comment: I don't see it in this script. The repositories are specified only in the buildscript block, but you have to specify them also outside this block.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using gradle build in offline mode. toggling offline mode solved my issue.